# why is the sequence of functions not continuous at each point?

Tags: analysis

Why is following  sequence of functions discontinuous everywhere??
$$f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
f(x)-\frac{1}{n},x \in \mathbb{Q}\\ 
f(x)+\frac{1}{n}, x \notin \mathbb{Q}
\end{matrix}\right.$$
where $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function

Comment: What do you mean by the _sequence_ being continuous or not? Each of the $f_n$ functions _itself_ is plainly discontinuous everywhere, but I don't think that the sequence of _all_ $f_n$s can _itself_ be said to be "not continuous". On the contrary, it converges uniformly to $f$.

Comment: Why is each of the $f_n$ functions itself plainly discontinuous everywhere??

Comment: x @evinda: Because in every interval it has function values that are at least $2/n$ away from each other.

Comment: @HenningMakholm How can I show it with the definition,using sequences?

Comment: @evinda are you able to see that the function
$$
\chi_\mathbb{Q}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
is discontinuous everywhere?

Comment: x @evinda: That $f_n$ is discontinuous has nothing at all to do with the fact that it's part of a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f_n(x)$ is continuous at a point $x_0$.  Then for every sequence $\{x_k\}$ for which $x_k \to x_0$, it must be that $\lim_{k \to \infty}f_n(x_k) = f_n(x_0)$.

If $x_0$ is an irrational number, choose a sequences of rationals $\{q_k\}$ for which $q_k \to x_0$, and note that $\lim_{k \to \infty}f_n(q_k) \neq f_n(x_0)$.  Similarly, if $x_0$ is a rational number, choose a sequence of irrationals $\{p_k\}$ for which $p_k \to x_0$, noting that $\lim_{k \to \infty}f_n(p_k) \neq f_n(x_0)$.

In either case, we note that $f_n$ cannot be continuous at $x_0$ for any $x_0$.

Comment: I understand..thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\chi_{\mathbb Q}$ denote the characteristic function of the rationals. Since 
$$f_n(x)=f(x)-\frac 1n+\frac 2n\chi_{\mathbb Q}(x),$$
it suffices to show that the characteristic function of the rationals is not continuous at any point.

Tis comes from the fact that each open non empty interval contains rationals numbers and irrational ones.

Comment: Couldn't we also show it,by using the definition?
So,we take a sequence of rational  numbers $q_k$ and a sequence of irrations numbers $a_k$..But why is then : $lim_{k \to +\infty} {q_k}=lim_{k \to +\infty} {a_k}=x$ ?

Comment: Yes, we can. We have to _choose_ these sequences convergent to $x$.

Comment: But,why is it possible that both sequences converge to $x$?? Do we know it from the density of rational and irrational numbers??

Comment: @evinda if you know that both the rational numbers and irrational numbers are dense, then it certainly follows that we can find both a sequence $q_k \to x$ and $a_k \to x$ as you've described.